# Travelling to the US on an L2 visa when separated

Tags: visas, esta

I have an L2 visa that's still valid and would like to visit my friends in the US in the next couple of weeks but unsure I'm able to use it.

Unfortunately, I'm separated from my husband who has the L1b visa.  He's from the UK but lives in the US whilst he still has his visa.

He's still in the US and both our visas are still valid.

Do you think I should apply for an ESTA or will I be ok on my visa? IF I did apply for an ESTA even though my visa is valid, would that cause issues too?

Comment: Separated or divorced? What is your nationality?

Comment: just separated.  We are both British, I live back in the UK and he still lives in the US

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is the slightest need of travelling together, so you should be good.

The 'dependency' of the L2 means that if your spouse loses the L1, you lose the L2 automatically too, but it doesn't mean you need to stay with each other when travelling.

My spouse often traveled alone on an L2, and they never asked where I am with the L1.

Comment: does it matter that I've not been to the US since last October?  And technically not been to the area my husband live since last April?

Comment: No, it doesn't, there is no limit on that visa, except the expiration date